# Assigning a Variable with the value from another shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to get a value from another shell script and assigning it to a variable in a shell script

I tried with the below command. But it's not working

```
BundleVersion= $(sh VersionNumberScript $(PLISTPATH))
```

Can I know what's wrong in the above command

Comment: Probably you want `$(PLISTPATH)` to be `$PLISTPATH`, in addition to the note about the space after the equal sign, which should not be there.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice this. Well, unless `PLISTPATH` is a command, but it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra space after `=`, which shouldn't be there. The syntax for assignment in shell is:

```
variable=value
```

If you write

```
variable= value
```

it will be interpreted as

```
variable='' value
```

which stands for "execute command 'value' after setting environment variable 'variable' to the empty string".

Comment: I have tried this but its not working. When I'm trying to run the script its printing, but its not getting assigned to a variable

Comment: @Icoder: It's hard to diagnose, when you don't even mention in which shell you are executing this command. The following applies, if it's in bash: First, a program named PLISTPATH is executed (in a child process), and its standard output is collected. Then, the program `VersionNumberScript` is executed (either as Posix-Shell or as Bourne Shell, depending on where you are on), and receives the previously collected output as parameter(s). Finally, the output of `VersionNumberScript` is stored in the variable `BundleVersion`.